# Print all items in NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uitextview

My program has a tableview, I want to show selected items from the tableview in a textview

I have following code **which shows only the last item of the NSMutablearray** in textview:

I guess problem is the **for loop** but couldnt figure it out.

stands is NSMutablearray, selectItems is NSMutablearray, selected items is UItexview.

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    [selectItems addObject:[stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
    for (NSString *yourVar in selectItems) {

        selectedItems.text=yourVar;
        NSLog (@"Your Array elements are = %@", yourVar);

    }

    [self.mytableView reloadData];
}
```

I try the following but it crashes:

```
[selectItems addObject:[stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  
int length = [selectItems count];

    for(int i=0;i<=length;i++){
        selectedItems.text= [selectItems objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

how can I show all  the items of NSmutablearray in a texview ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    [selectItems addObject:[stands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    
    NSMutableString *exString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *yourVar in selectItems) {

        NSLog (@"Your Array elements are = %@", yourVar);
        [exString appendFormat:@"\n%@",yourVar];

    }
    selectedItems.text=exString;

    [self.mytableView reloadData];
}
```

What about something like this?  It takes each object, puts a newline in it, then adds it to exString to form one long chain of the objects in your array.

Comment: You need to make exString an NSMutableString, and also do `[exString appendFormat:@"\n%@", yourVar]`. `stringByAppendingString` returns a new string but you're ignoring it.

Comment: didnt work, NSlog still prints all items in yourVar but can't see any thing in textview

Comment: Done.  You might try moving the `.text` part into the loop.

Comment: No moving .text in to loop was not the solution, Kurt Revis gave the answer when i change the string to NSMutaableString it worked, thank you

Comment: My code was updated to reflect that fact.  @KurtRevis, thanks for your help, and remember to mark as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly allocated and inited selectItems. Just adding objects does not create the NSMutableArray. Then you also need to concatenate your elements instead of overwriting the UITextView over and over again.

Comment: they are allocated like **stands = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    selectItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];**